# Custom Magento Extension Enable and Disable by my custom admin module

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, extensions, custom

How can i control my Custom Magento Extension from admin panal

**What is System.xml ?**

To view data and most i want to enable and disable module by my custome admin site

i want my own functionality for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to really disable your module is to change

```
<active>true</active>
```

to

```
<active>false</active>
```

in your `app/etc/modules/foo.xml`

If you want an admin account to be able to do it in the back-end, you can create a config option (with system.xml) to control your module. Although it's not exactly the same as disabling your module, you can make sure your module doesn't do anything by looking at the store config.

Comment: how to Create this system.xml and which code can disable module

Comment: There are plentiful tutorials for that if you do a couple Google searches @vaibhavahalpara